# Trouble applying the Tan double angle formula for $5\tan(2\theta)=4\cot(\theta)$

Tags: trigonometry

I have to solve the following equation
 $$5\tan(2\theta)=4\cot(\theta),\space \space \space 0°<\theta<180°$$

Applying the double angle formula for $\tan(2\theta)$

$$\frac{10\tan(\theta)}{1-\tan^2(\theta)}=4\cot(\theta)$$

I did solve and simplify this further but did not arrive at a correct value for $\theta$ so I decided to confirm where I went wrong on wolfram alpha, and to my surprise my very first step turned out to be wrong.

[image: Wolframalpha computation]

What mistake have I made here, is the double angle formula I have applied, $\tan(2\theta)=\dfrac{2\tan(\theta)}{1-\tan^2(\theta)}$, wrong or is there some restriction upon applying it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

The identity which you have applied is correct. More precisely, we have that
\begin{align*}
\tan(2\theta) = \frac{\sin(2\theta)}{\cos(2\theta)}
= \frac{2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{\cos^{2}(\theta) - \sin^{2}(\theta)}  = \frac{2\tan(\theta)}{1 - \tan^{2}(\theta)}
\end{align*}

Consequently, the proposed equation is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
5\tan(2\theta) = 4\cot(\theta) \Longleftrightarrow \frac{10\tan(\theta)}{1 - \tan^{2}(\theta)} = \frac{4}{\tan(\theta)}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

You are not applying the correct input to Wolfram Alpha.  The symbol `=` represents an assignment operator.  The symbol `===` represents `SameQ[]` in the Wolfram language, and tests whether two things are *identical*.  Neither of these is proper.  Do not try using Wolfram Alpha to check your work unless you understand its syntax and limitations.

The identity $$\tan 2\theta = \frac{2 \tan \theta}{1 - \tan^2 \theta}$$ is correct, however, there are some restrictions due to discontinuities and periodicity.  That said, we can deal with this in the normal course of searching for solutions.

For the given equation, let $z = \tan \theta$.  Then $$5 \tan 2\theta = \frac{10z}{1-z^2},$$ and $$4 \cot \theta = \frac{4}{z}.$$  Consequently $$10z^2 = 4(1-z^2),$$ from which we obtain $$z^2 = \frac{2}{7}.$$  Hence $$\tan \theta = \pm \sqrt{\frac{2}{7}}.$$  If we take the positive root, then $\theta$ is in quadrant I or III.  If we take the negative root, then $\theta$ is in quadrant II or IV.

In the first case, we may take $$(\sin \theta, \cos \theta) = \pm \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3},  \frac{\sqrt{7}}{3}\right),$$ where the sign must be the same for each coordinate.  In the second case, we may take $$(\sin \theta, \cos \theta) = \left(\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3},  \mp \frac{\sqrt{7}}{3}\right),$$ where the signs must be opposite for each coordinate.  Now all that is left is to check that these possibilities all work.